# Ukrainian short-term visa

Tags: visas, ukraine

I would love traveling to Ukraine. I have Indonesian ordinary passport and Hungary residence permit. Does it mean that I can travel to Ukrainian without any visa?

*I checked on this website http://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-requirements-for-foreigners They mention Indonesia require visa, Hungary is not but they didn't mention about residence permit from EU countries are required or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Ukraine does not accept Hungarian residence permit.

As an Indonesian citizen, you can get a visa on arrival at [Kyiv Boryspil Airport](http://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-boryspil), Kyiv International Airport (Zhuliany) and Odesa International Airport for a stay up to 15 days.

Comment: @Oscar Remember to bring a hotel confirmation, which will likely be required at the visa counter